# vTiger doesn't recognize any user

Tags: crm, vtiger

I having a problem using vTiger.
Actually i had no problems but we had to format one of our servers and as the SQL has been backup'ed i had no worries about vTiger.
Just got vTiger folder backup'ed too, but when i had my server back and put the folder of vTiger into www and restored the database i had a few errors, mostly resolved by re-configuring config.inc.php because paths had changes. But after all the configuration is done again i can't login to my vTiger. He reachs the database but does not recognize any of the users. I alway get username or password is wrong. Have anyone experienced this? Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem a few days ago, it turns out my cookies were corrupt (Firefox). I cleared all related cookies, problem solved. Try first using some other browser to confirm. hth.

Answer (score 1):

First I would check if the db is reached and populated with your data. Try connecting from the command line.

If you are working on Windows and have changed Vtiger's path, and you are using the bundled version, MySql path changes as well, but the Windows service can still be alive on the old path: in this case you must manually cancel the service and afterwards use the "Start Vtiger" button in order to create the new service.

Second, I would turn on the php debugging as explained [here](http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/vtiger520%3aDeveloper_Debug_Techniques). In most cases, these steps should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked user_privileges folder? in that you must have 2 files for particular user. eg. your user admin having id 1 in database then you must have user_privileges/sharing_privileges_1.php and user_privileges/user_privileges_1.php file

and open user_privileges_1.php file and check username/password in that file, if it's not same with your DB then change it manually.

Try this solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: try deleting the user_privileges_1.php file (make a copy first). I suspect the file will be re-created automatically, with the correct contents.